# How do I count how many milliseconds it takes my program to run?

Tags: c++, timer

This will show how many seconds:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int times,timed;

    times=time(NULL);
    //CODE HERE

    timed=time(NULL);
    times=timed-times;
    cout << "time from start to end" << times;
}
```

This will show how many ticks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int times,timed;

    times=clock();
    //CODE HERE

    timed=clock();
    times=timed-times;
    cout << "ticks from start to end" << times;
}
```

How do I get milliseconds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refer to question "[Convert Difference between 2 times into Milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487146)" on Stack Overflow.

Or use this:

```
static double diffclock(clock_t clock1,clock_t clock2)
{
    double diffticks=clock1-clock2;
    double diffms=(diffticks)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    return diffms;
}
```

Comment: why do you use (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)? Isn't CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000, so CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000 = 1, and it's meaningless to divide by 1.

Comment: That link goes to an answer for the `C#` programming language.

Answer (score 7):

If you use a Unix OS, like Linux or [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X), you can go to the command line and use the line

```
time call-program
```

The time command times how long the execution of any command line takes, and reports that to you.

I don't know if there's something like that for Windows, nor how you can measure miliseconds inside a C/C++ program, though.

Answer (score 3):

There's a `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` macro to help you convert ticks to milliseconds.

There are O/S-specific APIs to get high-resolution timers.

You can run your program more than once (e.g. a 1000 times) and measure that using a low-resolution timer (e.g. some number of seconds), and then divide that total by the number of times you ran it to get a (higher-resolution) average time.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, you can use [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx), which is in milliseconds.

Comment: "The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds."

Comment: @ChrisW: there was no specification that the resolution should be higher.

Comment: You're right; I'm just warning the OP that although `GetTickCount` returns a value that's measured in milliseconds, it isn't accurate to the nearest millisecond: instead it's accurate to the nearest 'tick' which is what he already had (and was trying to get away from) in his OP.

Answer (score 1):

Under Win32, you can access the high-resolution timer using [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) (IMHO that should be preferred, possibly with fallback to `GetTickCount`). You can find the example in Community Content section on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Below C++ program calculates the time elapsed for a simple code in milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, and seconds. It includes the `<chrono.h>` header which provides access to the current time using `system_clock()`. The `system_clock()` is designed to represent the real-time and used by all processes running on the system.

##### Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    sleep(2);

    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cout << "Elapsed time in microseconds: "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
         << " µs" << endl;

    cout << "Elapsed time in milliseconds: "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
         << " ms" << endl;

    cout << "Elapsed time in nanoseconds: "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count()
         << " ns" << endl;

    cout << "Elapsed time in seconds: "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(end - start).count()
         << " sec";

    return 0;
}
```

##### Output:

```
Elapsed time in microseconds: 2000127 µs
Elapsed time in milliseconds: 2000 ms
Elapsed time in nanoseconds: 2000127736 ns
Elapsed time in seconds: 2 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

> This will show how many ticks:
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <time.h>
> using namespace std;
> int main(void)
> {
>     int times,timed;
>
>     times=clock();
>     //CODE HERE
>
>     timed=clock();
>     times=timed-times;
>     cout << "ticks from start to end" << times;
> }
> ```
>
> How do I get milliseconds?

`clock()` returns milliseconds. Compile this code, it will return 1000. Of course if your on Linux and not on Windows replace `#include <windows.h>` with `#include <unistd.h>` and replace `Sleep(1000)` with `usleep(1000000)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long x = clock();
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Difference: %d", clock() - x);
}
```