# DateTime difference

Tags: c#

How can I calculate the difference between 2 `DateTimes`?

```
DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
DateTime b = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
int differenceInMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Did you actually read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx)?

Comment: [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326709(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487146/convert-difference-between-2-times-into-milliseconds

Comment: The difference is one hour :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minus is overloaded, use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx):

```
double differenceInMilliseconds = (b - a).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` values can be subtracted from one another resulting in an instance of a `TimeSpan`.

So

```
DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
DateTime b = a.AddHours(1);

TimeSpan difference = b - a;
double differenceInMilliseconds = difference.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Note that TotalMilliseconds is a `double`, not an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

[DateTime.Subtract Method (DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx)