# Time elapse computation in milliseconds C#

Tags: c#, time, timer

I need to time the execution of a code sequence written in C#. Using DateTime.Now I get incorrect values for the millisecond field. 
   For example:

```
 int start_time, elapsed_time;

 start_time = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

 for(int i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++) {
       // cpu intensive sequence
 }

 elapsed_time = DateTime.Now.Millisecond - start_time;
```

elapsed_time gives negative values.

How may I replace DateTime in order to obtain the actual value of the elapsed time?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` ???

Comment: Sure it will give you sometimes a minus value
You are not taking the timestamp, you are taking only a portion of it only.
Explanation:
DateTime.Now.Second = 50
After 15 Seconds DateTime.Now.Second will be 5, not 65
Thats why you are getting the negative values. This applies to Hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
So best thing to do is, either a stop watch, or two DateTime instances, one for start and one for end, var st =DateTime.Now
Console.Write((DateTime.Now - st).ToString())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring code execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376191/measuring-code-execution-time)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

//...

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++) {
    // cpu intensive sequence
}
stopwatch.Stop();
elapsed_time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 17):

### Answer EDITED based on comments

This answer is only trying to count the total elapsed Milliseconds between two times, where the times are derived directly from `DateTime.Now`. As per the conversation, it's understood that `DateTime.Now` is vulnerable to outside influences. Hence the best solution would be to use the `Stopwatch` class. Here's a link that better explains (IMO) and discusses the [performance between DateTimeNow, DateTime.Ticks, StopWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243351/environment-tickcount-vs-datetime-now).

**Original Answer**

The way you cast it into a int is the issue. You need better casting and extra elements :)
This may looks simple compared to an efficient timer. But it works:

```
DateTime startTime, endTime;
startTime = DateTime.Now;

//do your work

endTime = DateTime.Now;
Double elapsedMillisecs = ((TimeSpan)(endTime - startTime)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

There is a [reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61964/Performance-Tests-Precise-Run-Time-Measurements-wi) on the web, you may want to check out as well.

Comment: but DateTime.Now.Millisecond returns an int

Comment: That has nothing to do with the issue.  `DateTime.Now` returns the system time as a file time, which can vary a bit for any of a dozen reasons.  `Stopwatch` laboriously sets how many system ticks elapse per second/millisecond/etc and basically sets up its own environment to do the measurement.  This is exactly what you *need* to do when benchmarking things like this, so it is *repeatable*.

Comment: I was about to ask about the differences between them, so thanks

Comment: You guys are too fast to comment while I have been writing my answer. :) Take a look at the complete answer please.

Comment: @YYY Since someone has downvoted me and my answer works, I was curious to research. And I found out some great sources/proofs. :) Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487146/convert-difference-between-2-times-into-milliseconds). It has answers that are similar to mine.

Comment: @bonCodigo The link you provided is a completely different application, if for no other reason than *it's a web/forms application, not a benchmarking application.*  I didn't downvote you, but whoever did was fully justified because you are using the wrong tool for the job at hand.  If you would like to dispute the point, you should start with showing that `DateTime.Now` cannot be influenced by outside factors.  Considering that it pulls its values *specifically from* an outside resource, I think you'll find this difficult.

Comment: If we breakdown OP's main intention, that he wants to find out the total elapsed time in milliseconds between a start time and an end time. So I provided the answer according to that, and it works. **HOWEVER** , when I understand that " the solution should be independent of any influences on DATETIME.NOW " ---> that clearly means my answer can't be used. So I will put a note on the answer in that case. But again as for the logic, this does the job of finding elapsed time in milliseconds between two times IGNORING any influence on DateTime.Now

Comment: I don't think the `(TimeSpan)` cast does anything

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.  It is specifically designed to bring back high-accuracy time measurements.

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

stopwatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++)
{
     // cpu intensive sequence
}
stopwatch.Stop();

var elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 4):

Stopwatch there are examples in the URL 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8

```
using System.Diagnostics;
//...
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
// here the complex program. 
//...
watch.Stop();
TimeSpan timeSpan = watch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}h {1}m {2}s {3}ms", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, 
timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime.Millisecond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx) just returns the millisecond fraction of the second, from 0-999. You would need to take the rest of the datetime into consideration when doing timings.

However, you should look at using the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class for these kinds of performance timings.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var lapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(beginTime).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to obtain the time for a simple computation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Decimal p = 0.00001m;
        Decimal i = 0m;
        DateTime start = new DateTime();
        DateTime stop = new DateTime();

        for (i = p; i <= 5; i = i + p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("result is: " + i);
            if (i==p) start = DateTime.Now;
            if (i==5) stop = DateTime.Now;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Time to compute: " + (stop-start));

    }
}
```