# Measuring code execution time

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime, timespan

I want to know how much time a procedure/function/order takes to finish, for testing purposes.

This is what I did but my method is wrong 'cause if the difference of seconds is 0 can't return the elapsed milliseconds:

Notice the sleep value is 500 ms so elapsed seconds is 0 then it can't return milliseconds.

```
    Dim Execution_Start As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

    Dim Execution_End As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
    MsgBox(String.Format("H:{0} M:{1} S:{2} MS:{3}", _
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Execution_Start, Execution_End), _
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Execution_Start, Execution_End), _
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Execution_Start, Execution_End), _
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Execution_Start, Execution_End) * 60))
```

Can someone show me a better way to do this? Maybe with a `TimeSpan`?

The solution:

```
Dim Execution_Start As New Stopwatch
Execution_Start.Start()

Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

MessageBox.Show("H:" & Execution_Start.Elapsed.Hours & vbNewLine & _
       "M:" & Execution_Start.Elapsed.Minutes & vbNewLine & _
       "S:" & Execution_Start.Elapsed.Seconds & vbNewLine & _
       "MS:" & Execution_Start.Elapsed.Milliseconds & vbNewLine, _
       "Code execution time", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Comment: @Soner If I tagged it with C# is because C# code is welcome for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Execution time of a Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130232/find-execution-time-of-a-method)

Comment: Besides the obvious reasons to use a stopwatch, you should never do any math with `DateTime.Now` due to Daylight Savings and Time Zone issues.  Please read [my blog post on this very subject](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the execution time of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

A better way would be to use [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch), instead of `DateTime` differences.

[Stopwatch Class - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch)

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to
> accurately measure elapsed time.

```
// create and start a Stopwatch instance
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 

// replace with your sample code:
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: @ElektroHacker, you are welcome, its easier to use, plus it is more accurate then DateTime :)

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/chai-deshpande/LogExec (a NUGET package is also available https://www.nuget.org/packages/LogExec/). This does the exact same things that @soner-gonul mentioned - but, the usage is clutter free and hides all the boilerplate code. Very helpful when you want to use it very frequently. It also uses Common.Logging so that you can integrate with your preferred logging provider.

Comment: @Habib can you please help me to understand why is Thread.sleep(500) is necessary? Cant i do it skipping sleep, would that make it less efficient?

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam, there is no need to use `Thread.Sleep`, it just there as a sample code to show delay.... in fact you should avoid using `Thread.Sleep` anywhere in your code

Comment: But this does not measure the process time, so the result is affected by other processes running on the system.

Answer (score 72):

[`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) measures time elapsed.

```
// Create new stopwatch
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](https://ideone.com/KqT6fi).

Comment: can it used for execution time of each line of code? e.g:
bindingSource.datasource = db.table; // how much it takes long?

Comment: @vaheeds Sure. Just start this `Stopwatch` on top of your each line and stop it after your each line. Remember, you need to use also [`Stopwatch.Reset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.reset.aspx) on after every single line to calculate. Based on your line; take a look http://ideone.com/DjR6ba

Comment: i did a little trick on it to get the miliseconds out of picture. this way watch.Elapsed.ToString().Split('.')[0]

Comment: @Doruk Yeah, you can do that or you can use [Custom Timespan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) like `stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm\:ss")` which seems a cleaner way to me.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 61):

You can use this Stopwatch wrapper:

```
public class Benchmark : IDisposable 
{
    private readonly Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    private readonly string benchmarkName;

    public Benchmark(string benchmarkName)
    {
        this.benchmarkName = benchmarkName;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"{benchmarkName} {timer.Elapsed}");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var bench = new Benchmark($"Insert {n} records:"))
{
    ... your code here
}
```

Output:

```
Insert 10 records: 00:00:00.0617594
```

For advanced scenarios, you can use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) or [Benchmark.It](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Benchmark.It/) or [NBench](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBench/)

Comment: Thank, best answer so far

Comment: Thanks, Was looking for such in centralized way. Have done this strategy with ActionFilter as well.

Comment: Not only this is a great answer, but also I learn something new from it too! Well Done Bud!

Answer (score 16):

If you use the Stopwatch class, you can use the **.StartNew()** method to reset the watch to 0. So you don't have to call **.Reset()** followed by **.Start().** Might come in handy.

Answer (score 5):

Stopwatch is designed for this purpose and is one of the best way to measure execution time in .NET.

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
/* the code that you want to measure comes here */
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Do not use DateTimes to measure execution time in .NET.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for the amount of time that the associated thread has spent running code inside the application.
You can use `ProcessThread.UserProcessorTime` Property which you can get under `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

```
TimeSpan startTime= Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[i].UserProcessorTime; // i being your thread number, make it 0 for main
//Write your function here
TimeSpan duration = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[i].UserProcessorTime.Subtract(startTime);

Console.WriteLine($"Time caluclated by CurrentProcess method: {duration.TotalSeconds}"); // This syntax works only with C# 6.0 and above
```

Note: If you are using multi threads, you can calculate the time of each thread individually and sum it up for calculating the total duration.

Answer (score 3):

Example for how one might use the Stopwatch class in **VB.NET**.

```vbnet
Dim Stopwatch As New Stopwatch

Stopwatch.Start()
            ''// Test Code
Stopwatch.Stop()
Console.WriteLine(Stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString)

Stopwatch.Restart()            
           ''// Test Again

Stopwatch.Stop()
Console.WriteLine(Stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString)
```