# C# calculate time stamp

Tags: c#

I want to check the amount of time it takes for a specific function to be performed ,so that I will add accurate time delay on my program...
I tried to write this before and after my function:

```
public static String (this DateTime value)
{
   return value.ToString("mmssffff");
}
```

Then I calculated the difference between both results, and I get 350.I do not know if it microseconds or milliseconds...

Do you know the meaning of the result?(350)
Do you have another idea to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make it easy on yourself and use `value.ToString("mm:ss:ffff");`? You'll know immediatly what gives the output.

Comment: I don't see any `TimeStamp` in your code..

Comment: Don't use `DateTime` to measure elapsed time but [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Have you looked at using the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376191/measuring-code-execution-time

Comment: No...what is StopWatch?

Comment: @Tehila: Read the MSDN docs. Is it still unclear? It's really just the same as the real world entity 'stopwatch'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use profilers for this task. In many cases the single method takes a lot of time but a sub-method which should be executed instantly takes most of the time. In fact, I was working on a Java project before and I have observed that it took unreasonably much time to work out the solution. I have used a profiler there and have seen that a simple object instantiation took most of the time. The problem was, of course, that the Java library initialized a hole lot of things because of that constructor, so I have chosen an alternative instead. So, I think you should use a profiler, read more [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to start working with C# profilers.

Comment: It looks complicated .. But I'll try.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for performance profiling.

```
 Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();
  SayHello();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("Total time elapsed {0} millseconds", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

I normally use something like this:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// rest of the code
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Total time (ms): {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Why cast a `long` to a `long`?

Comment: Sorry, don't need the cast. Edited.