# Time execution of a program

Tags: c#, profiling

**What is the best way to time how long a program runs for?**  I have a code and need to find out how long it will run. It seems to me that the best way - is to start a timer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new {MyEnumerator = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.GetEnumerator()};
        while (x.MyEnumerator.MoveNext())
            Console.WriteLine(x.MyEnumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean, how long did it run, use a Stopwatch.

Comment: Have you ever looked at [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class? From documentation; _Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time_

Comment: @PeterRitchie Be careful, Peter.  You neither camelCased nor hyperlinked the word "Stopwatch" - not everyone knows what that is!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring code execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376191/measuring-code-execution-time)

Comment: Keep in mind that you should time your code multiple times (e.g. in a for loop or similar construct) and take the average or fastest time or whatever you'd like. For instance, the first time a method is called might take significantly longer than subsequent calls.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Stopwatch *is* camel cased, stopwatch is a one word.  I know of only one Stopwatch in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Stopwatch` to see how long code took to run:

```
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var x = new {MyEnumerator = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.GetEnumerator()};
    while (x.MyEnumerator.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(x.MyEnumerator.Current);
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's 1 way of doing it. With the `Stopwatch` class.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Create new stopwatch
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Begin timing
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Do something    
    var x = new {MyEnumerator = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.GetEnumerator()};
    while (x.MyEnumerator.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(x.MyEnumerator.Current);

    // Stop timing
    stopwatch.Stop();

    // Write result
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create and start a new stopwatch with the `StartNew()` method.

Comment: Thanks @PeterRitchie Wasn't aware of that. I learn something new everyday on StackOverflow :)