# Telegram Bot Api getUpdates vs setWebhook methods

Tags: c#, .net, telegram, telegram-bot

Which method in telegram bot api more effective, getUpdates or setWebHook? Which one is faster?

P.S. 
I use telegram-bot api for C#.

Comment: Check it by yourself.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376191/measuring-code-execution-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically getUpdates used for debugging. For publishing your bot you need to use Webhook.

> getUpdates is a pull mechanism, setWebhook is push.
>   There are some advantages of using a Webhook over getUpdates:
>
> 1. Avoids your bot having to ask for updates frequently.
> 2. Avoids the need for some kind of polling mechanism in your code.

See [this useful document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks).