# Is there a difference between Car[] (array) and IEnumerable<Car> when using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In several projects I am using the mapping functions of AutoMapper. I will use the object **Car** as an example through the full question.

First my **set-up**:

I define my maps with profiles:

```
public class CarProfile : Profile
{
    public CarProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Car, CarResponse>();
    }
}
```

I **initialize** AutoMapper in ASP.NET Core Web API with:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Using the NuGet packages `AutoMapper` and `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

The mapper is automically injected in the constructor and set as a private field `_mapper`.

Eventually I **map a collection** with the following piece of code:

```
_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Car>, IEnumerable<CarResponse>>(_context.Cars);
```

It's also worth to mention that `_context.Cars` is in this case an `DbSet<T>`.

Now my **actual question** is: would it be different if I would use an `array` instead of a `IEnumerable`.

**Example given**:

```
_mapper.Map<Car[], CarResponse[]>(_context.Cars);
```

Please consider performance, clean code and behavioural differences.

Comment: Why wouldn't you measure performance yourself? (https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Good point, will do. If however anyone knows please still answer.

Comment: I doubt the collection type will matter nearly as much as the complexity of the object graph being mapped. Doing bulk mappings is slow regardless of using `Array` or `IEnumerable`

Comment: One thing to consider - is Automapper smart enough to map things one at a time, so for instance if the `Car`s were coming from a streaming source (a DB for example), it could map them as they're enumerated, rather than mapping the whole collection.  I've not used it enough to know - may be worth looking in to.

Comment: I agree that the difference may be irrelevant, but I am still interested in the outcome :)

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Understanding-your-mapping).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Do you have any resources on how to utilize this execution plan? I have generated it, but can't really get the information I am looking for out of them.

Comment: As that link explains, you get what gets executed. At this point, it's just C# code. That's all the information you need.

Comment: Any ideas on what I can do to edit this question so that it is not too broad and still valuable for the community? Or would it be better to close?

Comment: Closing would be best.

Answer (score 1):

**Behavioural differences**

I generated the execution plan and I can conclude that there at least *is* a difference. See this link for my comparison: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=elujt . Analyzing the C# code makes clear that there happens more when using an array.

**Performance**

Since this still does not give any insights in performance, I measured that using [Stopwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16376203/869033).

```
        var watchienumerable = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var ienumerable = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Car>, IEnumerable<CarResponse>>(contextDevices);
        watchienumerable.Stop();
```

Measuring IEnumerable first:

- IEnumerable: 21 milliseconds;
- Array: 7 milliseconds;

Measuring Array first:

- IEnumerable: 7 milliseconds;
- Array: 21 milliseconds;

These results are not representative, because the mapper still needs to be warmed up.

Mapping a collection related to this object first (to warm up the mapping, initialize caching etc.)

- IEnumerable: 57704 ticks;
- Array: 122014 ticks;

I can conclude that mapping to an IEnumerable from (something that is not an array) is faster than mapping to an array. With hindsight, it sounds quite obvious.

When the input is an array:

- IEnumerable: 18642 ticks;
- Array: 1392 ticks;

It's also worth to mention that if use the actual type of `_context.Cars` which is `DbSet<Car>`. It is exactly as fast as when I use `IEnumerable<Car>`.

Word of advice: I would use the type that is closest to the input and still matches your desired output.
In my case, I will stick to using IEnumerable.

**Clean code**

This part of my answer is highly opiniated and very open to comments. But I think `Car[]` reads better  than `IEnumerable<Car>`.

However since there are behavioural and performance differences I don't think it's clean to use an array here. It also changes the intent. So using `IEnumerable<T>` would be better.